# How do i restore my git repository after using git -r rm

Tags: git, reset, revert

I was playing round with my repository and after modifying some files I used:

```
git add .
```

the output of this was:

```
 Changes to be commited:
      new file:   path/to/file.txt
      modified:   path/to/file2.txt

 Changes not staged for commit:
      deleted:     path/to/file/file3.txt
```

so I used:

```
 git commit -m 'add and modify file and file2'
```

which gave the output:

```
 2 files changed, x insertions, x deletions
```

so I did git status which gave the output:

```
 Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory

           deleted:
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and or "git commit -a")
```

so at this point i did:

```
git rm -r .
```

as i thought this would remove all of the 'deleted' files
However this removed everything in my repository

I then did:

```
git reset HEAD .
```

after which I did git log and found the commit code for the commit I did originally in this post. This just reverted me to previous to that commit.

What I want/need is to get all the files back after the first commit 'add and modify file and file2'

Is this possible from here? I dont want to play with it anymore as I dont want to mess it up further! Thanks

Comment: What do you get from `git reflog`?

Comment: cg27dhj8 HEAD@{0}: add and modify file and file2
e72js921 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to dev
91j897ss HEAD@{2}: pull origin master: Fast-forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

You were on the right track using `git reset HEAD` to restore your files. As long as you didn't commit the deleted files, you can simply add the `--hard` option to also restore the files in your working directory:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

### The Three Modes of `git reset`

The `git reset` command is able to modify three things in your repository:

- The `HEAD` reference
- The Index
- The Working Directory

What is going to be modified depends on the mode of operation you choose:

- `--soft` modifies just the `HEAD` reference
- `--mixed` modifies the `HEAD` reference *and* the Index
- `--hard` modifies the `HEAD` reference, the Index *and* the Working Directory

If you invoke `git reset` without specifying one of these three arguments, the default is going to be `--mixed`. This means that Git is going to move the `HEAD` reference and update the Index but will leave your Working Directory intact.

In your case, you want to restore the files in the Working Directory as they were in your latest commit (referenced by `HEAD`) so you need to pass the `--hard` option:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

You can read more about how `git reset` works in the excellent blog post [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html).

Answer (score 1):

From git logs, check which is the correct commit id you want to roll into (check time or number of commits to verify):

Then use:

```
git reset --hard <tag/branch/commit id>
```

Comment: as in if the git log code is cg27dhj8. and i want to go to exactly the state of this when it was commited (i.e like it was straight after i committed this) I use: git reset --hard cg27dhj8 ?

Comment: Yes, if you have to revert to commit id cg27dhj8, that's how you would use git reset command